# The term 'deno' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: api, visual-studio-code, deno

I installed `Deno` using Powershell, even though, I got this error in my `Visual Studio Code` How can I verify ?

```
The term 'deno' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify 
that the path is correct and try again.
```

[image: error]

Comment: Is Deno installed properly in your machine?

Comment: If I typed deno in command prompt, i got the deno version, so i think installed correctly,

Comment: please check the following link for set up deno https://www.loginradius.com/engineering/blog/hello-world-deno/

Comment: you also need to download the deno package for  visual studio code .

Comment: I wrongly installed `Deno` in PowerShell without run as **Administrator**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Deno did not install properly.

> 1. Open Powershell and **Run as Administrator**
> 2. After that, if you are using windows type this command to install properly
>
> 3 . `iwr https://deno.land/x/install/install.ps1 -useb | iex`

Comment: that blog doesn't contain anything about **Run as Administrator**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. deno run index.js didnt work in VSCode terminal but deno worked in powershell.
What I did? I simply closed the VSCode and opened it again. "WALLAH!" it worked!